# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module

Tags: angularjs

ncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: We'd need more code to evaluate this. Are you loading the .js where you define your app `(angular.module('myApp', []);`? Did you define it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: https://codepen.io/ahmedsamirbek/pen/xLqPXz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created an anonymous function, but never invoke it:

```
(function() {
  var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
  myApp.controller("FirstController", function($scope) {
    $scope.Name = "Ahmed";
  });
})() // add the ();
```

Also, to make your codepen work, I had to fix the angular import:

```
<script 
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.4/angular.js" 
    type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>angularJs</title>
    <script src="angular-1.6.4/angular.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>

</head>

<body  >
    <div ng-controller="FirstController">
        <span>{{Name}}</span>
    </div>
    <script>
        (function(){
            var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);         
            myApp.controller("FirstController", function ($scope) {
               $scope.Name="Ahmed"; 
            });

        });

    </script>
</body>
```